# Cannot launch Repl() in Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, unit-testing, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm writing UITests on Xamarin

I try to launch the Repl window, but it doesn't launch.

My code:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using NUnit.Framework;
using Xamarin.UITest;
using Xamarin.UITest.Android;
using Xamarin.UITest.Queries;

namespace MurakamiKiev.UITests
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class Tests
    {
        AndroidApp app;

        [SetUp]
        public void BeforeEachTest ()
        {
            app = ConfigureApp.Android.StartApp();
        }

        [Test]
        public void ClickingButtonTwiceShouldChangeItsLabel ()
        {
            app.Repl();
        }
    }
}
```

This is, how I try to launch Repl:

[image]

That  is, what I have in Console.

[image]

What wrong with my code??

I tried  breakpoints, but nothin happens.
I tried  to update references, but it didn't help. 
Or if issue not in code, how I can launch Repl window?

Help me please I wrote Xamarin forums, but don't have answer.

**UPDATE**

I try to use Debug and x86

Have this error

```
    Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       java.lang.OutOfMemoryError. Consider increasing the value of $(JavaMaximumHeapSize). Java ran out of memory while executing 'java.exe -jar C:\android-sdk\build-tools\23.0.1\\lib\dx.jar --no-strict --dex --output=obj\x86\Debug\android\bin obj\x86\Debug\android\bin\classes "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v6.0\mono.android.jar" C:\Users\nemes\Documents\GitHub\Murakami_kiev\MurakamiKiev\obj\x86\Debug\__library_projects__\Square.OkHttp\library_project_imports\okhttp.jar C:\Users\nemes\Documents\GitHub\Murakami_kiev\MurakamiKiev\obj\x86\Debug\__library_projects__\Square.OkIO\library_project_imports\okio-1.6.0.jar C:\Users\nemes\Documents\GitHub\Murakami_kiev\MurakamiKiev\obj\x86\Debug\__library_projects__\Square.Picasso\library_project_imports\picasso-2.5.2.jar C:\Users\nemes\Documents\GitHub\Murakami_kiev\MurakamiKiev\obj\x86\Debug\__library_projects__\UrlImageViewHelper\library_project_imports\bin\classes.jar C:\Users\nemes\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Android.Support.Animated.Vector.Drawable\23.3.0.0\embedded\classes.jar C:\Users\nemes\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Android.Support.v4\23.3.0.0\embedded\classes.jar C:\Users\nemes\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Android.Support.v4\23.3.0.0\embedded\libs\internal_impl-23.3.0.jar C:\Users\nemes\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Android.Support.v7.AppCompat\23.3.0.0\embedded\classes.jar C:\Users\nemes\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Android.Support.v7.MediaRouter\23.3.0.0\embedded\classes.jar C:\Users\nemes\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Android.Support.v7.MediaRouter\23.3.0.0\embedded\libs\internal_impl-23.3.0.jar C:\Users\nemes\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Android.Support.Vector.Drawable\23.3.0.0\embedded\classes.jar C:\Users\nemes\AppData\Local\Xamarin\GooglePlayServices.Analytics\8.4.0\embedded\classes.jar C:\Users\nemes\AppData\Local\Xamarin\GooglePlayServices.Base\8.4.0\embedded\classes.jar C:\Users\nemes\AppData\Local\Xamarin\GooglePlayServices.Basement\8.4.0\embedded\classes.jar C:\Users\nemes\AppData\Local\Xamarin\GooglePlayServices.Maps\8.4.0\embedded\classes.jar'    MurakamiKiev
```

My Heap size is set to 1G

Any answers how I can launch Repl?????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look into adding platform specification for initializer

```
[TestFixture(Platform.Android)]
public class Tests
{
    IApp app;
    Platform platform;

    public Tests(Platform platform)
    {
        this.platform = platform;
    }

    [SetUp]
    public void BeforeEachTest()
    {
        app = AppInitializer.StartApp(platform);
    }

    [Test]
    public void AppLaunches()
    {
        app.Repl();
    }
}
```

Also I've noticed you have your project in Release mode - put it to Debug.

Comment: I have question. I need to debug on visual studio android emulator or on device?

Comment: will try now debug mode

Comment: Clean the project, do rebuild.    Also set  [TestFixture(Platform.Android)] or call app = AppInitializer.StartApp(Platform.Android) or this.platform = Platform.Android; My bad, didnt cpecify this in example's constructor

Comment: Check nunit version number - Xam doesnt support Nunit 3.0

Comment: 2.6.4 now is installed

Comment: Try Debug under Any CPU

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113999/discussion-between---and-dany-dakur).